# How to access the Started WebServer PlayFramework Application on Amazon Ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have create the Amazon Ec2 Instance and I deployed the Play Framework play 1.2.5 and Create the Project.

When I started the Project using `play start -httpD.port = 80`

The Application was successfully started and the log file thrown in that log file it shows waiting for initial response.

How to access that running server? I have entered my instance ip address along with port number in the as usual format but its not getting up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the TCP port in your AWS console:

- Go to the Security Group settings
- Find the Security Group that your instance is apart of
- Click on Inbound Rules
- Use the drop down and add HTTP (port 80)
- Click Apply